# Add UIView in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to create `UINavigationBar` with rounded corner. It will look like this
[image: rounded navigation bar]

What I am thinking is I add `UIView` with rounded corner and insert it in navigation bar. So this is my code

```
let roundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44))
roundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteBackground
roundView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20)
navigationController?.navigationBar.insertSubview(roundView, at: 0)
setTitleTextColor(color: UIColor.black)
```

By the UI, this works well. But then my `UIBarButtonItem` is missing, it covered up by my custom view and couldn't be clicked. So my question is, how to add subview in navigation bar?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `NavigationBar` and take `UIView` and customize it according to your need. Its better to do simply.

Comment: @dahiya_boy what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just not use UINavigation bar and create all by scratch. Is the easiest way. Otherwise you can try with pattern image:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need my navigation controller.

Comment: You can try with a pattern image, as I specified.

Comment: I ended up with using image as background. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From Storyboard,

1. You have ViewController with navigationController

[image]

2. Select `navigationController` and deselect the below selected option i.e. Show Navigation Bar visibility.

[image]

3. Take a UIView (purpleView) with constraints

   - top, leading trailing = 0 w.r.t. superview
   - height = 64
4. Take another UIView (whiteView) in purpleView with constraints

   - top= 20 (for status bar)
   - leading trailing bottom= 0 w.r.t. purpleView
5. Now add cancel and label to your whiteview
6. Now your UI Hierarchy is like below

[image]

[image]

7. Take outlet of whiteView and make corner radius

Thats it.

If you'r not using storyboard then you can do same with code also. In this case you have to set frame of purpleView and whiteView instead of constraints.

Hope now its clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

How about to make it as a normal UIView and hide the navBar and show it in the next VC, who will know which trick you have used.
[read this short article here](https://medium.com/@energized_mania_elk_101/how-to-use-uiview-as-navigationbar-which-allow-you-to-change-navigationbar-size-54bc5fc56d6c)